# Request Where _id on mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request

I am trying to make a request findOne() to my mongoDB

Here's my code:

```
if (result) {               
                users.findOne({
                    access_key: request.headers.access_key,
                    secret_key: request.headers.secret_key
                }, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        response.withStatus(500).apply();
                    }....
```

"result" contain my ObjectID and I would like to check if my access_key and secret_key correspond to my registered user to allow him to continue or not.
I would like something like this : "findOne access_key, secret_key where _id = result"

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Comment: Thanks @AlexBlex I already checked it.. But I don't understand how to make what I expect..

Comment: Then you probably need to learn some basic mongodb syntax. e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/ can be a good starting point. It is hardly possible to explain it better.

Comment: `                        users.findOne(
                            {
                                _id: ObjectID(result._id),
                                access_key: request.headers.access_key,
                                secret_key: request.headers.secret_key
                            }` seems to do the job, I tested it and it seems ok, tell me if I did a mistake please